# Initialize view controller with data from container view controller in storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I have a storyboard that uses a custom UIViewcontroller (we'll call it VC-A) which contains two container view controllers in its root view. I want VC-A to gather some data during its initialization and pass it to one of the child vc's during their initialization. I'm guessing that I do not understand fully the right flow for this to work as it doesn't seem possible. I can set values and run other operations overriding the initWithCoder method and setting VC-A as the delegate of one of the other child vc's (I can set VC-A as the child vc's delegate and the child vc can query vc-a for data but this can only occur AFTER the child vc has been initialized). Is there a way to do this? or more likely where am I missing the boat on the correct flow of information here? Thanks for reading!

In VC-A

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"collectionEmbed"]) {

}
if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"tableEmbed"]) {
    ImageTableViewController *utvC = (ImageTableViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
    [utvC setUnitArray:[self vendUnitList]];
//A check on the debugger here shows that [[self vendUnitList] count] returns 5
}
}
```

In VC-B (Subclass of TableViewController

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
// Return the number of rows in the section.
NSLog(@"%u",self.unitArray.count);
//Debugger shows this to be 0
return self.unitArray.count;
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

// Configure the cell...
UnitVO *unitVO = (UnitVO *)[unitArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSLog(@"Unit Name: %@",unitVO.unit_name);
cell.textLabel.text = unitVO.unit_name;
return cell;
}
```

Some loggin'

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
if(self.tableView.delegate == self && self.tableView.dataSource == self)
{
    NSLog(@"Yep");
}else{
    NSLog(@"Nope");
}
// Get Yep for output
}
```

Storyboard can be seen here:[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1IEeu.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use this in VC-A to set the values in VC-B

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
   [segue.destinationViewController setSomeValue:_someValue];
}
```

Hope I understood the question correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I think you understood the question bc this is exactly what I'm trying to do! Perhaps I've missed in the details though. Specifically I'm using VC-A to provide data to VC-B (B is a tableviewcontroller that vc-a gets the data for). As I understand it, by the time the framework gets to prepareForSegue, the child controllers are already instantiated so by the time I setSomeValue, the controller has laid out the view and is already initialized. I'm trying to set this data during the VC-B initialization phase

Comment: @CollinWhite have you tested setting the data with prepareForSegue? I have created a couple of prototype applications which will set the data for the UITableView in that method and the table is always populated with the data when it loads.

Comment: I've updated my post with some more code, maybe this will shed some light on where I'm going wrong, thanks for the help!

Comment: @CollinWhite hmmm, thats strange all looks good. Can you confirm that ImageTableViewController has been set as the data source and delegate for the table view. I would also check by manually setting some dummy data in the viewDidLoad method (of VC-B) to make sure everything is connected up properly.

Comment: No prob, I've posted some more code, doing something arbitrary like self.tableView.backgroundcolor = [UIColor redColor]; in the viewdidload changed the table to red

Comment: @CollinWhite call reload data after you have set the data. [segue.destinationViewController.tableView reloadData];

Comment: Brilliant! that did it...IB also inexplicably deleted my segue identifier...but thats for another time. Thanks you!